# How can I add padding to a <td> without effecting the background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook, html-email

I'm looking for a solution where I can add padding to the 'h1' tag. The markup below allows me to render the background image in outlook. However by doing so when I add padding to the `td`, padding is added to the background - which is not the result I want. Does anyone know how I could add padding to the `h1` that is compatible with outlook email clients?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:35px;" class="mbl-pad-1" background="images/banner1.jpg" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="600" height="248" valign="middle" >
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:248px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="images/banner1.jpg" color="#7bceeb" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->

                <h1 class="emailh1" style="font-size:65px; line-height:60px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:left; margin:0;">DO YOU TRUST<br/>YOUR SOURCE?</h1>

              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
              <![endif]-->

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your markup has multiple syntactical issues. Validate your HTML first.

Comment: Should be better now. Check it agian

Comment: i didn't see any `h2` tag in your html

Comment: Sorry, this is just a snippet from the main html file. I have edited it to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of finagling and the help of user Gortonington I was able to find a solution.By using the markup of found here [Bullet Proof Background](http://backgrounds.cm/) I was able to get the background image to display correctly in outlook. To add padding to the h1 tag I used the advice of Gortonigton and added an extra table with a width of 100% then added a padding style to the  to align the text properly. Thanks for everyone for the help!

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
        <td background="images/banner1.jpg" bgcolor="#333" width="100%" valign="top">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:248px;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="images/banner1.jpg" color="#333" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]-->
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                  <td class="mbl-pad-1" style="padding-left:35px; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px;">
                    <h1 class="emailh1" style="font-size:65px; line-height:60px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:left; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;">DO YOU TRUST<br/>YOUR SOURCE?</h1>
                  </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          </v:textbox>
          </v:rect>
          <![endif]-->
          </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nest a new table inside at 100% width and add padding to that td.

So basically:

```
 <td with background >
      <table width="100%">
      <tr>
      <td style="padding: Xpx;">your content</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `<div>` tag around the `<h1>` inside `<td>` and add the padding to it.

```
<td>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
</td>
```

//EDIT:

If this is only for email, I would just use tables to space it like so:

```
<td>
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="10"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10"></td>
            <td><h1>...</h1></td>
            <td width="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="10"></td></tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: I've tried this as well outlook does not render padding in the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **margin-left:35px;**  for H1 tag

```
<td>
<h1 style="margin-left:35px;"></h1>
</td>
```

Comment: I've tried this. Outlook does not support margin in the h1 tag